# Running openCV 2.4.11 on eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu, undefined-reference

I'm a student from germany and for my bachelor thesis I am required to run a programm and later do something with the output it gives me. However, the programm is written by using openCV and I have a lot of trouble configuring openCV on my PC. I already followed a lot of tutorials and I have openCV 2.4.11 installed on my PC correctly (I think).
Now I tried to test my setup using the following code from one of the tutorials:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    if( argc != 2 || !image.data ) {
        printf( "No image data \n" );
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display Image", image );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I properly told eclipse where my include files and lib files are and which of them to include. I don't get any errors in the code whatsovever.
But when I try and build my project, it won't work. Instead, I get an endless list of errors that lead to being unable to build it.

The errors read like (That's like 0.1 % of them):

```
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1158): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1c14): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1cbd): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `cv::mulSpectrums(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, bool)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1cfa): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [DisplayImage2] Error 1

16:04:37 Build Finished (took 660ms)
```

I googled the "Nicht definierter Verweis" part and found out that it is the german version of "undefined reference". However the solutions offered there did not solve my problem. I had the same problem in windows as well as on a different computer before but people told me it was Window's fault and that I should use ubuntu and all my problems would be gone.

I'm sorry if this was answered before and I just missed it. However I'd really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Did you use CMake to generate your Make file? If OpenCV has been installed properly on your computer, CMake should be able to find it automatically and generate the project files.

Comment: Try including `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.

Comment: Yeah I made the files using cmake. What do you mean by "find it automatically"?

Comment: If you have installed OpenCV package CMake can automatically prepare veriables for you to use them like that:
`find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) ` 
`target_link_libraries( project ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment here. I made the OPENCV Libaries using cmake. I did not build the tutorial file with cmake. Shall I try that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment, so answering:

Your undefined references are referencing functions (like `dft`) that are not being called in your code. You might be actually building something different than what you think.

Comment: Well, what am I building instead? I used the build all command in eclipse. Is that wrong? Also how can I make sure that I'm building the right thing?

Comment: I don't know what you're building :) I'm no eclipse except, but using "build all" indicates there might be more files in your project than the one you posted. If you have something similar to the Solution Explorer in VS, i.e. something that lists all files in your project, try to right-click on the file with your actual code and build only this one file.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful, here's a skeleton CMakeLists.txt file which will compile a opencv c++ file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(yourFileName)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} yourfile.cxx)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
${PROJECT_NAME}
${OpenCV_LIBS})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
```

If you run this directly through cmake either gui or command then it should work and then at least it will run so you can work out eclipse later..

Comment: Sounds helpful. I will try it out and see how it goes